# Why is force negative if PE increases?

Tags: forces, work, potential-energy, conventions

I'm looking at the PE vs force graphs for gravity, and it doesn't make sense to me. As potential energy increases (and the object goes higher above the ground), F=-mg. But if I'm raising an object up, it requires a force in the positive y direction, not negative, so I don't understand why F would be negative.

Similarly, if I drop an object from a height, it begins to lose potential energy, so the force graph should be positive. But this doesn't make sense, either, because gravity is providing a downward, negative-"y" force, so F should be mg.

And yet it isn't. I was thinking maybe I have the perspectives wrong (which direction the forces are acting), and maybe I do, but I can't seem to reconcile it without making my y-axis for force inverted from my y-axis for PE.

[image]

Comment: A link to the graphs you mention would be good.    The position of the object is irrelevant, but the direction it is moving is not.  In particular, the force and the displacement are both vectors.  Whether work is positive or negative depends on their angle.

Comment: Oh, I understand that. My problem is that for PE decreasing, the object is accelerating downward, and gravity is probiding a negative force. For PE increasing, I need to provide a force in the positive direction, no? So it seems to me like the signs of F and PE should be the same.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I don't think I can. I'm on mobile and don't see an option. EDIT Got it.  http://imgur.com/OMKbrWx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force is a vector. Potential energy is a scaler. Forces which have associated potential energy functions as called *conservative forces*. Conservative forces act in such a direction that, if released from rest, the potential energy function associated with *that* force will decrease (and the kinetic energy will thus increase) with the velocity increasing, until it hits some barrier (ground, floor, table, restrictive field, etc.) We call such a barrier a *constraint.*

The acceleration associated with the conservative force is always pointed in the direction of decreasing potential energy of the system due to that particular interaction.

Gravitational force acts "downward." The gravitational potential energy always decreases when you move downward. The acceleration of the gravitational force is downward.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. I was viewing the potential energy graph as something which could change slope as a function of time; in reality it's a function of position and so moving the opposite way doesn't make the slope negative, but just makes us travel back along the PE curve. For this mistake, I thought that as you invert the direction you travel, the line of mgh would curve back and forth, and the associated force would also flip between mg and -mg. I see this is not the case now, due to PE(g) being based on position it doesn't change slope so F is always negative. Thanks!